# Showing that $C^{-1\prime} \Omega C^{-1} = I$

Tags: linear-algebra

$\Omega$ is covariance matrix (symmetric, positive definite) and we defined $CC'=\Omega$ to be the Cholesky decomposition (lower triangular decomposition) of $\Omega$.

A text that I'm reading makes it sound obvious that

$C^{-1\prime} \Omega C^{-1} = I$

But I can't see it.

Specifically I have

$$
Var(\pmb b) = (X^{*\prime}X^*)^{-1}X^{*\prime}Var(\pmb \epsilon^*)X^*(X^{*\prime}X^*)^{-1}
$$

Where the $*$ means that the $X^* = C^{-1}X$.

I believe the middle term and the right term should end up cancelling out.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is over $\mathbb R$

$C^{-1\prime} \Omega C^{-1} = I\implies CC^{\prime} = \Omega = C^{\prime}  C$
but an upper triangular matrix commutes with it's transpose *iff* it is diagonal.  Conclude (i) $C$ is diagonal hence $\Omega$ is diagonal or (ii) this is a typo and the author meant  $ C^{-1}\Omega C^{-1\prime}= I$